# How to run Storm Topology class through command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, apache-storm, topology

Hi i have a single topology class with main method in it. It starts zookeeper and run in eclispe  right click run as java application. But i am trying it to be able to run through batch file i have tried

```
java -classpath jar-with-classes-and-dependency.jar com.demo.Topology
```

but this gives me exception like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
backtype/storm/generated/AlreadyAliveException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
backtype.storm.generated.AlreadyAliveException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I think this is about missing any dependency. 
Please help in running this topology class.

Comment: Actually i am trying to build a command to run this topology using batch file.

Comment: Post your main() method please

Answer (score 2):

Try running like this...

```
pathToStorm/bin/storm jar ./target/jar-with-classes-and-dependency.jar com.demo.Topology.
```

And remember, you should build your jar before doing this step. You can build your jar by running 
    `mvn clean install` inside your storm project where your pom.xml file is located.